# IntelliJ: Cannot Generate Dependencies (Alt+Insert) for Java/Gradle Project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Java/Gradle project that I imported into IntelliJ. When I open the Generate menu (Alt+Insert) for a `build.gradle` file, I don't see an "Add dependency..." option.

**Details:** I imported a multi-project Java/Gradle build into IntelliJ [New > Project From Existing Sources...]. The top-level project only has a `settings.gradle` file (excluding the `gradlew` scripts) that looks like this:

```
rootProject.name = 'project'

include 'subproject1'
include 'subproject2'
include 'subproject3'
```

When I open the `build.gradle` file for any sub-project, however, the Generate menu (Alt+Insert) doesn't have an "Add Dependency..." option. My only option is to manually type in the dependency.

Other Notes:

- I also don't see a "Dependencies" option in the "View > Tool Windows" menu.
- When I manually type in the dependency, auto-complete still works.
- AFAIK, all other Gradle functionality works just fine in IntelliJ.
- I also have a separate single-project Java/Gradle build that I created via IntelliJ [New > Project...], and I can generate dependencies just fine in that project.

**Versions:**

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- Gradle 7.3.2 [installed via snap]
- OpenJDK 17 [installed via apt]
- IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition) [installed via snap]